# Can we print docx file without open with any office dll?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, openxml, office-interop

Can I print and PDF docx file without open into winword by VSTO or OOXML from MS-office installed desktop/server? Is any DLL is there to do?

I need to make print and PDF bunch of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can: 
there are lot's of libraries. Like:

- [Free Word API to Operate DocX documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX_Doc/) - Convert your docx to pdf and then print it.
- [Apsose Word](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx): It's some kind of the standard library to work with docx in .Net, but not really cheap.

In addition you can find some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313503/printing-an-ooxml-document-without-ms-word-installed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359055/printing-docx-without-ms-word-automation).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will review this, the reference link says without winword installed. but I have installed winword application the desktop system, then why cannot use Office supprt package to print without open the file?